# Trouble converting Javascript source to Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a Javascript function to Python. Most of it was no problem but there's one statement I'm not sure how to convert:

```js
color = +("0x" + color.slice(1).replace(color.length < 5 && /./g, '$&$&'))
```

The Python so far is:

```py
color = +("0x" + color[:1].replace(
            len(color) < 5 and /./g, '$&$&')
        )
```

idk what `+()` or `/./g` are for. The complete JS function is:

```js
function lightOrDark(color) {
    
    // Variables for red, green, blue values
    var r, g, b, hsp;
    var threshold = 127.5
    // Check the format of the color, HEX or RGB?
    if (color.match(/^rgb/)) {
        
        // If RGB --> store the red, green, blue values in separate variables
        color = color.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?\)$/);
        
        r = color[1];
        g = color[2];
        b = color[3];
    } else {
        
        // If hex --> Convert it to RGB: http://gist.github.com/983661
        color = +("0x" + color.slice(1).replace(color.length < 5 && /./g, '$&$&'))
        console.log(color)
        r = color >> 16;
        g = color >> 8 & 255;
        b = color & 255;
    }
    
    // HSP (Highly Sensitive Poo) equation from http://alienryderflex.com/hsp.html
    hsp = Math.sqrt(
        0.299 * (r * r) +
        0.587 * (g * g) +
        0.114 * (b * b)
    )
    
    // Using the HSP value, determine whether the color is light or dark
    return hsp > threshold;
}
```

Comment: The first question to ask is "what does it do" because you could port the exact code, but it's infinitely better to write pythonic code that does the same thing as the necessarily rather different JS code because of the differences between the two langauges' standard libraries. Ignore the Python code now: explain what the JS does by looking purely _at_ the JS. What's the expected content of `color`? Given that, what does the code do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sure, if you're not confused about the syntax. I've never seen that type coercion before. It's unusual and reminded me of lambda calculus for a moment. I also had forgotten that there are regexp objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/./g` is a regular expression and the `+()` coerces a string into a number (and the `0x` makes it hexadecimal). In Python you'd use the `re` module and the `int()` builtin for that.

The `replace` duplicates the characters if the color is written in its short form. The Python equivalent is a `re.sub()`. You use a backslash instead of a dollar for back-references in Python's regex dialect. So `\1` refers to the first matching group.

```
>>> import re
>>> color = "#123456"
>>> re.sub("(.)", r"\1\1" if len(color)<5 else r"\1", color[1:])
'123456'
>>> color = "#abc"
>>> re.sub("(.)", r"\1\1" if len(color)<5 else r"\1", color[1:])
'aabbcc'
```

So for a short string, this replaces each character with itself twice, but for a long string this replaces each character with itself once (no change).

Then you use a base of 16 to convert a hexadecimal string to an int:

```
>>> int('aabbcc', 16)
11189196
```

All together:

```
int(re.sub("(.)", r"\1\1" if len(color)<5 else r"\1", color[1:]), 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a fairly compact line of code. Let's deconstruct it.

First, `+()` is the same as `Number()` in this case it can also be alternatively implemented using `parseInt()`.

Next `/./g` is just a regular expression. On its own it does not do anything. It is just a value like `"hello"` or `3`. It is the first argument to `replace()`.

So the line can be rewritten as:

```
let temp1 = color.slice(1); // In this case can also be rewritten as color.substr(1)
                            // It basically removes the first character

if (color.length < 5) {
    temp1 = temp1.replace(/./g, '$&$&'); // This replaces each character with itself twice.
                                         // For example "123" is replaced with "112233"
}

let temp2 = "0x" + temp1. // This adds "0x" to the previous string so that
                          // it will look like a hexadecimal number.

color = parseInt(temp2); // Convert string of hexadecimal number to a number.
```

I personally don't know Python but the above should be easy to rewrite in any language.

In case you're not comfortable with regular expressions you can rewrite the number doubling code using a loop. The following is an alternative implementation that does not use any fancy functions/methods at all:

```
// Remove first character (color.slice(1))
let temp1 = "";
for (let i=1; i<color.length; i++) { // copy every character except color[0]
    temp1 = temp1 + color[i];
}

// Convert 3-letter color to 6-letter color, eg #69a to #6699aa
if (color.length < 5) {
    let temp2 = "";
    for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
        temp2 = temp2 + temp1[i] + temp1[i];
    }

    temp1 = temp2;
}

let temp3 = "0x" + temp1. // This adds "0x" to the previous string so that
                          // it will look like a hexadecimal number.

color = parseInt(temp3); // Convert string of hexadecimal number to a number.
```

Note that both versions of the code above does exactly the same thing as the line:

```
color = +("0x" + color.slice(1).replace(color.length < 5 && /./g, '$&$&'))
```